# Doctrine Autoloader appending namespace to include path

Tags: php, doctrine, autoload

I have the following folder setup

```
/common
   /classes
     -sharedClass.php
/project
   /classes
       -coreClass.php
   index.php
   bootstrap.php
```

In my bootstrap.php I'm setting up a namespace

```
$autoloader = new ClassLoader('CommonFiles', dirname(__DIR__) . '/common/classes/');
$autoloader->register();
```

In index.php:

```
require_once 'classes/coreClass.php'
$core = new CoreClass();
```

in coreClass():

```
use CommonFiles\SharedClass;

//Other code
```

I'm getting an error that sharedClass.php can't be found, and the actual namespace is being appended to the file path being checked so that it's:

```
c:/web/common/classes/CommonFiles/sharedClass.php
```

So... how do I stop the autoloader from including the namespace as part of the path root it's looking for?

Answer (score 0):

So after some closer review apparently this is just how autoloading works.  I reviewed some of the baked in Doctrine samples and it looks like the namespace is appended automatically to all your use statements.  This wasn't just a fluke but a design decision and accounting for it meant an easy fix.